# Usage of EXISTS in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

---

**EDIT 2:**
What I want to ask is: If I understood right, an `EXISTS` statement does not *filter* any tuples from a relation. So for what purposes is it used, since it does not *filter* any tuples?

**EDIT:**
To elaborate more, in the first example, the following is present in the subquery:

```
cities_stores.store_type = stores.store_type
```

but as far as I understood, if the subquery evaluates to `TRUE`, then what will be returned is *all* `DISTINCT store_type`s `FROM stores`, is that right? If so, how is that useful?

---

[Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html), it is stated that a `[NOT] EXISTS` statement will evaluate to either `TRUE` or `FALSE`. In the two examples existing in the link, if I assume that first example's `EXISTS` statement and second example's `NOT EXISTS` statement will evaluate to `TRUE`, then the examples are supposed to be equivalent to the following:

Example 1:

```
SELECT DISTINCT store_type FROM stores
  WHERE TRUE;
```

Example 2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT store_type FROM stores
  WHERE TRUE;
```

If that's the case, then both queries are equivalent, provided that their `[NOT] EXISTS` statements evaluate to `TRUE`. So my question is, how is using a `[NOT] EXISTS` statement is useful? How do they work? If what I stated is wrong, could you please point out wrong places and explain how do `[NOT] EXISTS` statements work?

Comment: The power is what the sub query is doing, per their examples

Comment: Get all records having no link to another table. That is a useful *not exists* query

Comment: You're onto something. EXISTS does appear to have some magic going on when it references columns from the outside SELECT. In would much rather opt for a JOIN which seems much cleaner.

Comment: @Biscuits Thank you. Actually I would be very happy if you could have time to elaborate with an answer.

Comment: @Utku I'm not sure if I have an answer. It is however easier to make peace with it if we pretended it was a normal scalar function that gets called numerous times, once for every row in the outside SELECT, that returns a boolean value to indicate whether the outer-row stays or drops off. Then, the fact that SQL Server optimizes this internally to behave like, what appears to be a JOIN, should be trivial for the purposes of explaining the logical outcome.

Comment: @Utku Remember, SQL is a declarative programming language, so although you may be able to break down queries (statements) into logical selects and sub-selects, it is the statement in its entirety that captures the command.  Therefore, queries aren't similar at all if their entire statements don't match.  It is a mistake to think that a select physically selects from a sub-select, for example. Ultimately, with the grander statement in mind, SQL Server decides.

Comment: @Utku This nature of queries appear to be wide-spread, and is referred to as correlated or synchronized sub-queries. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery

Comment: @Biscuits Thank you. The link you provided is really good. I will go through it and post here if there are still unclear points. Thanks again.

Comment: @Utku I've posted the best answer I could come up with. I hope it helps. Please remember to send some votes if you find comments or answers useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you're referring to uses correlated sub-queries.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery

Here's an excellent answer explaining the mechanics behind it.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11592277/2707705

Comment: Please remember to vote for answers you find useful.

Answer (score 0):

Note this statement in the subquery `"WHERE cities_stores.store_type = stores.store_type"`. it is where the inner table checks against outer table. in the examples, cities_stores is the inner table, stores is the outer table in the main query.

> EDIT 2: What I want to ask is: If I understood right, an EXISTS statement does not filter any tuples from a relation. So for what purposes is it used, since it does not filter any tuples?

The filter you are looking for is in the subquery - `"WHERE cities_stores.store_type = stores.store_type"`. not every record in table 'stores' will return true from the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Exist statements do the same as

```
select * from mainTable
Where (select count(*) from subTable where related condition) > 0
```

but with one exception it stops after the first match

Not Exist is the natural extension of this statement

Comment: Thanks. Actually I guess I was not able to clearly state what I wanted to ask. What I wonder is, as far as I understood, an EXISTS statement does not *filter* any tuples. So how and where is it useful?

Comment: practical example ,you are bookings.com ,the user has supplied you with a city and date range ,your task is to list just the hotels in that era,one way to do it is to select from the hotels where city_ID = :CITY_ID and    exist (select * from availability where hotel_ID = hotel_FR  and dates between :START_DATE and :END_DATE), this will list just the hotels